# Request for invalid marker set

Tags: google-maps

I've installed [gmap](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap) module and configured it so that I'm using custom markers. It worked well till today (I've re-deploy website).

I'm able to choose my custom marker 'Accountant' in a settings (see screen below).
[image]

However when I load map I get an error message: "Request for invalid marker set"
[image]

I've googled it and did not find a clear explanation what is wrong.

Please advise what could be an issue.

Comment: There are [several results](https://www.google.com/search?q=drupal+gmap+%22Request+for+invalid+marker+set%22&gws_rd=ssl) for this error. For example, did you try to follow advice given at https://www.drupal.org/node/2164713#comment-8526941? Also, it would be useful, if you could post any errors, that might appear in browser's console.

Comment: Hi Miloš Kroulík, thanks for that. I tried once and it did not work for me (later I realised it was due to access), so thank you! you were right, that was my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an update "REGENERATE MARKER CACHE" option in gmap settings.

[image]

By pressing "Regenerate" button Drupal will update JS file stored in

```
/sites/default/files/js
```

Make sure you have access to that file.